# “Unable to locate adb” bug via Android Studio

Tags: device-manager, android-studio, sdk, adb, bug

0

I'm 2 months into Android Studio,I run the latest version(4.0.1 for Windows 64-bit) to be precise and also run the latest gradle offline build dependencies. So far,I've setup my Android Sdk well enough and the Platform_tools folder is up to date(including the full adb setup) But each time i try to run my Emulator(Nexus 5 API 21), i get an Error

The first thing it tells me is "unable to locate adb" then it shows me a file showing: "The ADB binary found at C:\Users\CHINEZ\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe is obsolete and has seriousperformance problems with the Android Emulator.Please update to a newer version to get significantly faster app/file transfer.(it as well partly displays the emulator)

Then at event log it shows me "Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037"

I have tried all adb related solutions on this site like;

*Avast virus chest *Deleting and replacing the android platform_tools Unchecking and deleting the older sdk versions *Selecting use detected adb location *Deleting and and running the AVD and so many other things...but none of them worked for me Even watched a lot of youtube videos,all to no avail

Please can anyone help with other possible solutions to this bug that i can try on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the installed version is too old,
download and install the latest version of `adb`.

From
[Android Debug Bridge (adb)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb):

> `adb` is included in the Android SDK Platform-Tools package. You can download this package with the [SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager), which installs it at `android_sdk/platform-tools/`. Or if you want the standalone Android SDK Platform-Tools package, you can [download it here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools).

Comment: I've downloaded both the new standalone adb you just sent now and the new platform tools already,installed in the directed location,still didn't solve the issue

Comment: Do you have more than one installed version of adb?

Comment: No,only one is currently installed on my system

Comment: Check the Properties of the file `C:\Users\CHINEZ\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe` under Details to verify that it's the latest version.

Comment: Checked,  Adb version - 1.0.41, version 30.0.4-6686687.I believe that's the latest?

Comment: This seems the latest. Check in Task Manager if there isn't some other `adb.exe` already running. Perhaps you could uninstall your version and try the one from SDK Manager.

Comment: I checked task manager,I didn't even see any adb.exe running. I uninstalled my version and installed this one directly from sdk manager today

Comment: What to do next?

Comment: As a last resort, I would uninstall everything using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/), then install Android Studio and use SDK Manager to install adb.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reinstalling Android SDK after deleting the platform-tools dir but with no success. What did work for me were the following steps:

1. In Android Studio go to File > Project Structure (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S in windows);
2. Under Project Settings>Project>**Project SDK** must have a **valid Android SDK** selected;
3. emulate a new device;
4. check if the adb daemon is running and recognizes the emulated device: open cmd prompt, run `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\adb.exe devices` and it should list the device you have on atm.